# Where does the intuition for a coin flip approaching a 50:50 heads tail split for larger n come from?

Tags: probability

Given that the formula for the odds of an even split for $2n$ flips is $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2n!}{n!^2}$, this means that as the

the number of flips increases, the chances of obtaining an even split become smaller. If you flip a coin
 $100$ times the odds of getting $50$ heads are $0.079$. So why then if a coin is flipped $1000$ times,   do we get a distribution that is close to a $50:50$ split most of the time?

Does the basis for that intuition come from the fact that we sum the probabilities of all combinations that we consider close to an even split (such as $485 H: 515 T$)  and combine them?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia’s Law of Large Numbers Page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)

> For example, a fair coin toss is a Bernoulli trial. When a fair coin is flipped once, the theoretical probability that the outcome will be heads is equal to 1/2. Therefore, according to the law of large numbers, the proportion of heads in a "large" number of coin flips "should be" roughly 1/2. In particular, the proportion of heads after n flips will almost surely converge to 1/2 as n approaches infinity.
>
> Though the proportion of heads (and tails) approaches 1/2, almost surely the absolute difference in the number of heads and tails will become large as the number of flips becomes large. That is, the probability that the absolute difference is a small number, approaches zero as the number of flips becomes large. Also, almost surely the ratio of the absolute difference to the number of flips will approach zero. Intuitively, expected absolute difference grows, but at a slower rate than the number of flips, as the number of flips grows.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the basis for that intuition come from the fact that we sum the probabilities of all combinations that we consider close to an even split (such as 485 H: 515 T) and combine them?

Short answer: More or less.

Long answer: The **central limit theorem** tells you more precisely how the split is distributed. In particular, for any constant $c > 0$ and $n \to \infty$, the probability that the number of heads obtained on flipping the coin $n$ times lies in the interval $(\frac12 n \pm c\sqrt{n})$ goes to some nonzero constant. Also, the probability for the interval $(\frac12 \pm c)n$ goes to $1$. So if you fix a threshold of closeness of the **ratio** to half, the ratio will indeed be more likely to be close to half as $n \to \infty$. This does not contradict the fact that the probability of getting **exactly** half goes to $0$.